# Dúvida sobre WEBVIEW no Phonegap

Tags: apache-cordova, webview

Galera bom dia, eu não sei bem se isso é chamado de Webview, então corrija-me se eu estiver errado, por favor. Eu tenho um site, e estou introduzindo meus estudos agora em desenvolvimento de aplicativos, e pelo conhecimento que eu tenho em programação e desenvolvimento web, o Phonegap me pareceu perfeito. O que me remete a algumas dúvidas para o desenvolvimento desse projeto que estou em mente. Eu entendi que php não roda no phonegap depois de alguns minutos pesquisando, mas eu gostaria de saber qual é o caminho para renderizar um site dentro do aplicativo, eu sei que posso usar um iframe, mas ainda sim acho que tenho meios mais "profissionais" e úteis do que este. Por favor, quem puder me esclarecer eu ficaria muito grato. Desde já agradeço a atenção! Ótimo dia galera!

Comment: Você está com dúvidas de como salvar essas informações em um banco de dados ou como funciona a webview ? Eu recomendo conhecer o ionic.

Comment: Tipo assim, eu quero que o aplicativo apenas rode um site que já existe. De inicio isso vai resolver o meu problema.

Comment: Respondendo ao seu titulo: https://www.euconsertocelular.tk/reparocelular/android-webview-posso-desinstalar/

Comment: Basta você introduzir o seu site para dentro do phonegap e emular em sua aplicação.